# How to save a two dimensional char type array row-wise to a .txt file in c?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional char array[100][100] and I want to save it row-wise to a .txt file. By row-wise I mean first all the characters in the first row are printed, then second row and so on...

I can write the code for console output but don't know how to save it to .txt file:

```
for (int x=0;x<100;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<100;y++)
    {
        cout<<array[x][y];
    }
}
```

Please help me in this regards. Thank you.

Comment: Have your searched a bit on google?

Comment: Find out what `<<` means and what `cout` means then try to find something to do the same with a file.

Comment: and don't forget to add a whatever << ENDL; to split in rows :)

Comment: None of this answers my question :(

Comment: @user1486008: The top result from Google for the search string "write to file c++" details exactly how to do what you want. Put a bit of effort in. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: A simple google search would answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using std::cout;

int main(){
ofstream out("file_name.txt");
for(int x=0;x<100;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<100;y++){

              out << array[x][y];
        }
        out << "\n";


}
file.close();
return 0;


}
```

**using** `"\n";` rather than `endl;` will make your code faster since `endl` will flush your file stream buffer and write it to your file every row, which is 100 times. so it's better to not flush your file stream buffer until the end. in this case the close function will flush your buffer and close it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out("file_to_store_the_array.txt");
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
            out << array[x][y];
        }
    }
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  for (int x=0;x<100;x++)
  {
    for(int y=0;y<100;y++)
    {
      myfile<<array[x][y]; 
    }
    myfile<<endl;
  }
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Don't know if it compiles, but roughly should show you how's done. (the << ENDL; is for emitting a CR (or CR/LF depending on system) between rows)

Comment: Actually it is `endl`, not `ENDL`.